# Zend Framework: extend custom base controller from Zend_Controller_Action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller

I want my controllers to be extended from my base controller (no from Zend_Controller_Action).

How can I extend my base Contoller from Zend_Contoller_Action. And where this custom base controller to be placed so it will be accessible to other contollers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume, of course, you are aware of the arguments in favor of action helpers, for example, this article from Matthew Weier O'Phinney: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend write:

```
abstract class Mylib_YourBaseController extends Zend_Contoller_Action{
}
```

Create a directory called `Mylib` in the same place the `Zend` library is, that's it.

Comment: you allso need to register the namespace Mylib.

Comment: I use the old autoloader - don't need complex stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
My_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action { ... }
```

Place it in `library/My/Controller/Action.php` , then in you're app.ini ( or at bootstrap ) you need to register the namespace `My` , then all you're controllers can extend My_Controller_Action .